# How do I make drivers depend on time?

Tags: drivers

I want to animate an engine and want to make the piston move on the z axis like a sine wave, with the frequency depending on the position of a plane on the x axis, like this: sin("location of the plane"*100*"current frame") e.g. at frame 50 and the plane being at 2 on the x axis, the piston will be at z=sin(2*100*50)=sin(10000)=~-0.305

Can i do that? If yes, then how?

Comment: As shown [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#scripted-expression-orbit-a-point).. `frame` is a variable in the driver namespace, available to Scripted Expression drivers

Comment: Robin Betts This is an useful and (quite) hidden information, I think you should put it as answer, so it can be reached by many! :)